# Iterate through NSData and grab chunks

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

IS there any way to iterate through NSData so I can split it based on specific byte patterns? I need to break of certain chunks into an array for later look up.

Comment: problem is the range is variable I need everything between two byte tags.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To split an `NSData` on some separator, you can search for the separator with `rangeOfData:options:range:` and then split using `subdataWithRange:`. For example (based on some code I'm currently working on, but I haven't tested this specific block):

```
NSRange range = [data rangeOfData:delimiter
                          options:0
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, data.length)];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
  size_t body_offset = NSMaxRange(range);
  size_t body_size = data.length - body_offset;
  NSData *bodyData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(body_offset, body_size)];
  ...
}
```

This example searches for `delimiter` and assigns `bodyData` all the bytes after that. You could write similar code to split things up and add them to an array, or whatever you like.

One advantage of this scheme over rolling your own is that you will benefit from any optimizations inside of `NSData` that avoid memory copies. Apple doesn't promise such optimizations, but you can see that they're moving that way with `dispatch_data` and `enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:`. In fact, you should avoid `bytes` whenever possible (*), since that forces `NSData` to create a contiguous range, which it may have avoided up to that point.

For more, see the [Binary Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingBinaryData.html). (Note that this guide has not been updated for iOS 7, and doesn't discuss `enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:`.)

(*) "Whenever possible" is a little strong here, since you shouldn't make your code unnecessarily complicated just to avoid a call to `bytes` if memory copies wouldn't be a problem.